# get all the keys of dictionary that we have in a column of a dataframe

Tags: python

I have a data frame with one text column. I have to get keys of matching values as a new column. With the provided code below I'm getting just one key and it is going to next row without giving the second key. Please see a sample code that I have tried below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Dict_new = { 'key1': ['orange', 'yellow', 'blue'], 
                       'key2': ['red', 'saffron', 'purple'], 
                       'key3': ['white', 'grey', 'black']}
```

```
column of the data frame : 
white beard and purple hairs.
orange coloured car with black tilted windows.
eyes are red and grey hair.
```

I have got output as:

```
key3,
key1,
key2.
```

I'm getting only first key and I'm unable to go through further to get the second key.

Here is my code that I tried.

```
def new_code(x):
    for keys,  values in dict_new.items():
      for value in values:
        if value in x:
           return keys
df2['new_code'] = df1['column'].apply(new_code)
```

what I'm expecting as output:

```
new_code:
key3 key2,
key1 key3,
key2 key3.
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You `return` key if match is found, so it only iterate loop until first match will found.

Comment: I'm relatively new to python. can you suggest anything else other than return ?

Comment: without order : `df['column'].str.replace('.', '').str.split().apply(lambda x: dn.columns[dn.isin(x).any()].tolist())` where `dn = pd.DataFrame(Dict_new )`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

One caveat- you have to have text divided only by `space`, otherwise you either get rid of punctuation all together (which I do here, by `replace`, since you only have dots in your example), before doing anything, or you use `re.split()`.

```py
import pandas as pd
_data={'txt': ["white beard and purple hairs.", "orange coloured car with black tilted windows.","eyes are red and grey hair."]}

df=pd.DataFrame(data=_data)
Dict_new = { 'key1': ['orange', 'yellow', 'blue'], 'key2': ['red', 'saffron',
'purple'], 'key3': ['white', 'grey', 'black']}

df['new_code']=df['txt'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([k for k in Dict_new.keys()  if len(set(x.replace('.', '').split() ).intersection(set(Dict_new[k])) )>0 ]))

print(df)
```

output:

```py
                      txt   new_code
0       white beard and purple hairs.  key2 key3
1       orange coloured car with black tilted windows.  key1 key3
2       eyes are red and grey hair.  key2 key3
```

Comment: Hi @Spnash58 your suggestion is working great  on example data. I will check if this works on my main data. Many thanks.

Comment: Hi @Grzegorz Skibinski your suggestion is working on example data. I will check if this works on my main data. Many thanks